# Oracle's Collection<Object> tutorial is confusing

Tags: java, object, generics, collections

I'm learning Java generics and reading through [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

This page starts with

> Consider writing a method that takes an array of objects and a collection and puts all objects in the array into the collection

It then states

> By now, you will have learned to avoid the beginner's mistake of trying to use `Collection<Object>` as the type of the collection parameter.

The page infers that using `Collection<Object>` won't work.

Why is that an error? Why is it a beginner's error?

`Collection<Object>` as the parameter works fine for me. Am I so beginner that I've somehow made code that works, but misses the point of the exercise?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class test {

    static void fromArrayToCol(Object a[],Collection<Object> c)
    {
     for (Object x:a){c.add(x);}
     System.out.println(c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test r=new test();
        Object[] oa=new Object[]{"hello",678};
        Collection<Object> c=new ArrayList<>();

        test.fromArrayToCol(oa,c);
    }
}
```

It looks to me like Oracle's tutorial is wrong in its assertion. But I'm a beginner, so it's likely that I'm not grasping what it's trying to tell me.

Comment: It's poorly worded, but my guess is that what they mean is that, by now, you should know that it would be a **design** mistake, for two reasons explained before in the tutorial: 1. the whole point of generics is to constrain the type that the collection can contain and to avoid casts (and a Collection<Object> can contain anything, and thus doesn't constrain the type); 2. You want to be able to call the method with a Collection<String> for example if the goal is to copy an array of Strings to a Collection<String>, and as explained before, a Collection<String> is not a Collection<Object>

Comment: **The page infers that using Collection<Object> won't work.** Where?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer if you read the [Wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) section.

> The problem is that this new version is much less useful than the old one. Whereas the old code could be called with any kind of collection as a parameter, the new code only takes Collection, which, as we've just demonstrated, is **not** a supertype of all kinds of collections!

Here, old version refers to parameter `Collection` whereas new code refers to `Collection<Object>`

When you have a parameter of type `Collection<Object>`you can pass either a `Collection` (raw type) or a `Collection<Object>`. You cannot pass any other collection like `Collection<String>` or `Collection<SomeClass>`.

So, the goal of that tutorial is to copy the elements of an array containing *any type* to a new collection of the *same type*. 
*Example:* `Integer[]` to `Collection<Integer>`

I would say it wasn't worded properly to bring out the above meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It's often a mistake not because it's a compiler error but because having a `Collection<Object>` is very rarely useful. Such a collection can hold anything. How often do you need a collection that can hold anything and everything? *Very rarely*. There will almost always be a more specific type parameter you can use for your collection.

Using `Collection<Object>` more often than not just makes a programmer's life harder than it needs to be. To get anything out of it we need to inspect it's type (e.g. use `instanceof`) and cast it.

By using the most appropriate type parameter, you give yourself compile-time assurance that the collection will only contain the types of objects that you expect it will *and* the resulting code is more concise and more readable.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify. If you do not know the type of a collection at compile time you cannot put an element in it.

In your current example, you do know the type of object you wish to put into the collection (In your case its an object). The example shown on the site you liked is

```
static void fromArrayToCollection(Object[] a, Collection<?> c) {
    for (Object o : a) { 
        c.add(o); // compile-time error
    }
}
```

Notice that there is an `?` and not an `Object`. Hence you get a compile time error.

In the example you showed in your question which uses `Object` it does compile; however, there are better ways to solve this problem.

The biggest problem with that is that it only work on types that extend collection that have the generic type of Object. This makes it quite restrictive. The page is telling you that there is a way that will work for any collection and array as long as they hold the same type.

Answer (score 0):

`the beginner's mistake` they're referring to is the attempt to use `Collection<Object>` as parameter when you intend to accept **Any 
collection of something**.

Because `Object` is superclass of all java class, one may think `Collection<Object>` is "super-collection" of all collection. This point is demonstrated in the [Wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) section:

> The problem is that this new version is much less useful than the old one. Whereas the old code could be called with any kind of collection as a parameter, the new code only takes Collection, which, as we've just demonstrated, is not a supertype of all kinds of collections!

Instead of `Collection<Object>` you have to use `Collection<T>` to express that your method accept **Any collection of something**.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats also a option:

```
private <T> void arrayToCollection(T[] objArray, Collection<T> collection) {

    for (T obj : objArray) {
        collection.add(obj);
    }
}
```